# How is json decoding of utf emoji possible?

Tags: php, json, utf-8, emoji

As far as i call recall. A valid Json data comes in this format `'{"key":"value"}'`
But while surfing, I found an article about sending UTF-8 codes as emoji.
Emoji was stored in variable as
`$emoji = "\ud83d\udc4e";`. For it to work properly, the answer was to use `json_decode($emoji);`. I tried it out and it returned a *thumbs down* emoji. Meanwhile, I was expecting `NULL` but it turns out that it was a valid json data. So I'm confused how that is possible.

Comment: Why did you think it was going to be `null`? What was the JSON you tried to decode?

Comment: I think you're missing the fact that that string is literally `"\ud83d\udc4e"` _including_ the quotes. https://3v4l.org/0LbHP valid JSON can be things other than objects, including arrays and bare strings.

Comment: @sammitch all sample i've found are always in object and array format so i think i've been tied to that system of understanding JSON.

Comment: Have any available link or document that explains entirely about json?